# VCXO output frequency tuning

Tags: pll, vco

I am planning to use this VCXO [CVSS-945-100.000](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Crystek-Corporation/CVSS-945-100000?qs=2FIyTMJ0hNkfUCySmvRgxA%3D%3D) to generate 40MHz by providing the control voltage from a PLL.

The datasheet mentions control voltage as below:

[image]

Is it possible to generate 40MHz using this fixed VCXO, or should I use a VCO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Your control voltage can go from midpoint (2.5 volts) down to 0 volts and that will offset the frequency by 100 MHz x 25 ppm x 2.5 = 6.25 kHz for a 100 MHz device.

So, overall the 100 MHz device can be pulled in frequency by +/- 6.25 kHz.

Comment: I need to generate 40MHz, So I should use fixed VCXO which will generate 40MHz?

Comment: You could use a Colpitts oscillator. It all depends on how tight you want to control the frequency and what drift you can tolerate.

Comment: I could not find any VCO which would cover 40MHz frequency range. So far all the VCO's I found starting frequency is 100MHz to GHz range

Comment: You can make a VCO from a colpitts oscillator and a phase locked loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, the 100 MHz oscillator tuning range does not go down to 40 MHz. The range is only about 125 PPM

Comment: So I cannot use this fixed 100MHz VCXO to generate 40MHz by control voltage?

Comment: @MightyBeard0407 If I said no already, what makes you ask the same question again? Is there some improvement I can make?

Comment: No, It is cleared in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the -100  works at 100 MHz and the -40 works at 40MHz .

Although expensive, it is ideal for a sine output with low phase noise as stable as the source if it meets spec of 20ppm. A limiter is need for logic level may be included in your PLL.